# The correct way to store GlobalKey for Form in Flutter with Redux

Tags: flutter

I'm currently working on a project with Flutter using Redux.
I really like it when using Redux, majority of the Widget can be kept as `StatelessWidget` instead of managing States inside the `StatefulWidget`.

However I ran into some problem.

```
class MyForm extends StatelessWidget {
  GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: formKey,
      child: TextFormField(
        autofocus: true
        validator: someValidatorLogic
      )
    )
  }
}
```

What I need is `formKey` to do validation when button is pressed and I need to focus the `TextFormField` when the transition to the screen.

Since the `formKey` is class parameters, it seems to change every time. So what happen is that the TextFormField is automatically defocused every time.

Currently I store the GlobalKey in the Redux store, but it just feel really wrong to store it there because I feel that GlobalKey is parameter of the view. What is the correct way to store this key?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possibilities:

- Make it a static variable instead of a class field. Easy but implies that the widget can be used only *once*.
- Convert your widget to `StatefulWidget`. The go-to solution overall.

Answer (score 0):

covert to statefulWidget and this the code
**final _formKey = GlobalKey();**

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to:
improve code formatting
,
 include an explaination of how this works and why it is solution of the problem?
See [answer]